# Writing a dialogue with a lot of ellipses

Tags: dialogue, punctuation

Is there a way to do this properly?

> Roxas... I need you... to do me a favor. All those hearts that I've
>   captured... **Kingdom Hearts...** Set them free.

This is from Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days and I have no idea why there's a "Kingdom Hearts" in the middle. Can you explain what it's doing there? It sounds good, but logically, it doesn't make sense to me.

Is there a directive for putting random words that sound good in to dialogue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ellipses can also be used to indicate a pause in the character speech. Think of it like the trailing silence to a bad punchline or a slow fading out. Its longer than a full stop and there are no actions in between to indicate the passage of time, so you make do with an Ellipses.

Of course... having.. to many... makes the... sentence... terrible... to read...

In this case, I would think that the character is on their dying breath and that they have captured a physical/spiritual object called a **Kingdom Heart** which they then want to set free. The ellipses indicate that they are either short on breath or on their dying breath and they are having difficulties speaking properly.